# Raspberry Pi 3 model B SSH Connection refused

Tags: ssh

I just got an Rpi 3 model B and installed raspbian on my SD card. (in 2017)
then I powered it on for the first time and connected it to the ethernet. I found its IP address and tried to ping it. Ping works fine, However, when I tried to SSH it(ssh pi@xxx.xxx.x.xx), it says "ssh xxx.xxx.x.xx port 22: connection refused" Do I have to use a screen and keyboard & mouse to set it up? or if there's any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Official Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/) `ssh` is disabled by Default on Raspbian Jessie.

You will need a Screen and Keyboard to enable `ssh` using:

1. `sudo raspi-config`
2. Go to `Interfacing Options`
3. Enable `SSH`
4. Reboot your Pi